# Multiple threads add elements concurrently on different vectors of the same vector occurs error

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

struct A {
    std::vector<int> a;
};

struct B{
    std::vector<A> b;
    std::mutex mtx;
};

void work(int id, struct B& b) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(b.mtx);

    b.b.push_back(A());
    struct A& a = b.b.back();

    lck.unlock();

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        std::cout << id << " " << i << std::endl;
        a.a.push_back(i);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct B b;
    std::thread t1, t2;

    t1 = std::thread([&] {
        work(1, b);
    });

    t2 = std::thread([&] {
        work(2, b);
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

This code occurs some errors (like segmentation fault)

As I wrote above, `struct B` has a vector of `struct A` and `struct A` has a vector of `int`.

- Step 1) Each threads pushes new `struct A` element to the same vector (`b.b`) with critical section.
- Step 2) After then, each thread pushes new `int` element to the vector `a` of `struct A` each created without critical section.

I thought pushing new element to the same vector concurrently should occurs some problems, but pushing new element to the different vectors concurrently should not occur errors.

If I put whole `work` function into the critical section, it doesn't occur error.

So, I concluded pushing new element to the different vectors will not occur error, BUT if they are in the same vector, it occurs error.

But I cannot explain the reason. Someone please tell me about this. :(

Comment: I think I found the reason. As I push a new `struct A` to the vector `b.b`, vector `b.b` will be reallocated to increase the capacity. As result, `struct A& a` will be deallocated and it occurs error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the second thread pushes a new value to `b.b` this vector might get resized. If it gets resized all references to it's elements are getting invalidated. So the reference `A& a` of the first thread gets invalidated.

You could

- use a `std::list` (linked list)
- `resize()` the vector `b.b` before working with it, so it doesn't need to be resized later (or `reserve()`, doesn't make much of a difference here)

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` reallocates its memory when you `push_back`, because it needs additional memory. 
If you reserve() the vector, it won't reallocate until it needs additional memory.